# Model prediction for every possible outcome

Tags: r, regression

Let's say I'm running a model to look at questions asked on a form. My model looks like:

Price = B0 + B1(Gender) + B2(Age) + B3(Credit Type) + B4(Home) ...

I'm trying to calculate expected price for every possible scenario.

```
So price for gender = 0, age = 18, home = 1, etc.
Price for gender = 1, age = 18, home = 1, etc.
... and so forth
```

In R, is there a way to get the predicted price (output) for all possible combinations of the independent variables.

```
library(car)
mod = lm(sold ~ age + gender + marital + educ + cars + license + credit + type + home + id)
summary(mod)
```

EDIT:
After reading some of the comments below, I realized the stupidity of what I was doing. But I'm still wondering if there's a way to find the expected price. A general measure of what would the price be given the values/variables in this model.

So lets that that from the model, is there a way to glean the expected price. Let's say that it's $10 given the model.

EDIT 2:
Actually, just to figure it out in R, can anyone point to how I can perform the original task. The predicted value for all variations of the predictors.

Comment: Surely age will be a CTN variable and not a factor?

Comment: age is a numeric variable. How does affect things?

Comment: That means that age can take infinitely values: 18, 18.00001, 18.00002,.... plus lots of values inbetween

Comment: I know there are only 20 or so acctual ages and they are all whole numbers. Do you reccomend saving them as factors and then work on find the expected price for each age.

Comment: Hmm...20 ages times 2 genders times 3+ marital statuses times 3 to 20 or so levels of educational attainment times at least two "licenses" (whatever those are) times ... etc. = a minimum of 20,000 combinations (and likely millions).  What useful purpose will this exponential explosion of numbers serve?

Comment: Oh, wow, I hadn't thought of that. Then I might just consider finding the expected 'price' given the model. Just one value that the model would predict as the expected price.

Comment: To obtain an expected price--which is feasible--you need to assume a multivariate distribution of all the independent variables.  Do you have data to support such an assumption?

Comment: @whuber the purpose of it would be to know the sold price for every possible scenario.

Comment: That knowledge is compactly and efficiently expressed in terms of the fitted coefficients: in effect, they tell us *everything* that would be in that huge table of numbers you propose to compute and they are far more accessible.  Therefore people usually publish those coefficients alone.  To help with the interpretation, especially in communications with non-technical audiences, they sometimes provide the estimated value for a middle or typical combination of independent values and then explain the marginal-change interpretation of the coefficients themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could build a data frame of all the possibilities via `unique` and `expand.Grid`:

```
all.x <- expand.grid(gender=unique(gender),age=unique(age),...)
```

Then pass `all.x` into the predict method for your model.